# Problems during compilation of ros-indigo-qt-gui-cpp in Arch Linux ARM

Tags: robotic-arm, ros, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I get the following error:

```
==> Starting build()...
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/hiago/packages/qt_gui_core-release-release-indigo-qt_gui_cpp-0.2.30-0/src/build/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/indigo
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/indigo
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python2 (found version "2.7.12") 
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python2
-- Using default Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/em.pyc
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Skip enable_testing() when building binary package
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/hiago/packages/qt_gui_core-release-release-indigo-qt_gui_cpp-0.2.30-0/src/build/test_results
-- Found gtest: gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.6.18
CMake Warning at /usr/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:743 (message):
  Imported targets not available for Boost version 106200
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:842 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1395 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package)


CMake Warning at /usr/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:743 (message):
  Imported targets not available for Boost version 106200
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:842 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1395 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package)


-- Boost version: 1.62.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   filesystem
--   system
CMake Warning at /opt/ros/indigo/share/python_qt_binding/cmake/shiboken_helper.cmake:17 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindShiboken.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Shiboken",
  but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Shiboken" with any
  of the following names:

    ShibokenConfig.cmake
    shiboken-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Shiboken" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Shiboken_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "Shiboken" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  src/qt_gui_cpp_shiboken/CMakeLists.txt:41 (include)


CMake Warning at /opt/ros/indigo/share/python_qt_binding/cmake/shiboken_helper.cmake:21 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindPySide.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "PySide", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "PySide" with any
  of the following names:

    PySideConfig.cmake
    pyside-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "PySide" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "PySide_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "PySide"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  src/qt_gui_cpp_shiboken/CMakeLists.txt:41 (include)


CMake Warning at /opt/ros/indigo/share/python_qt_binding/cmake/shiboken_helper.cmake:34 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindGeneratorRunner.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this
  project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "GeneratorRunner", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "GeneratorRunner"
  with any of the following names:

    GeneratorRunnerConfig.cmake
    generatorrunner-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "GeneratorRunner" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
  set "GeneratorRunner_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.
  If "GeneratorRunner" provides a separate development package or SDK, be
  sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  src/qt_gui_cpp_shiboken/CMakeLists.txt:41 (include)


CMake Warning at /opt/ros/indigo/share/python_qt_binding/cmake/shiboken_helper.cmake:41 (message):
  Shiboken binding generator NOT available.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  src/qt_gui_cpp_shiboken/CMakeLists.txt:41 (include)


-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python2 (found suitable version "2.7.12", minimum required is "2.7") 
-- SIP binding generator available.
-- Python binding generators: sip
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/hiago/packages/qt_gui_core-release-release-indigo-qt_gui_cpp-0.2.30-0/src/build
[  7%] Building CXX object src/qt_gui_cpp/CMakeFiles/qt_gui_cpp.dir/recursive_plugin_provider.cpp.o
[ 14%] Building CXX object src/qt_gui_cpp/CMakeFiles/qt_gui_cpp.dir/settings.cpp.o
[ 21%] Building CXX object src/qt_gui_cpp/CMakeFiles/qt_gui_cpp.dir/__/__/include/qt_gui_cpp/moc_plugin_bridge.cxx.o
[ 28%] Linking CXX shared library ../../devel/lib/libqt_gui_cpp.so
[ 78%] Built target qt_gui_cpp
Scanning dependencies of target libqt_gui_cpp_sip
[ 85%] Running SIP generator for qt_gui_cpp_sip Python bindings...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/share/python_qt_binding/cmake/sip_configure.py", line 50, in 
    config = Configuration()
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/share/python_qt_binding/cmake/sip_configure.py", line 19, in __init__
    ['qmake', '-query'], env=env, universal_newlines=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 567, in check_output
    process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1343, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
make[2]: *** [src/qt_gui_cpp_sip/CMakeFiles/libqt_gui_cpp_sip.dir/build.make:90: sip/qt_gui_cpp_sip/Makefile] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:375: src/qt_gui_cpp_sip/CMakeFiles/libqt_gui_cpp_sip.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:128: all] Error 2
==> ERROR: A failure occurred in build().
    Aborting...
```

I've done my best, but till now i coudn't figure out what to do to solve this problem.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248064/problems-during-compilation-of-ros-indigo-qt-gui-cpp-in-arch-linux-arm/) by [emersonjr](https://answers.ros.org/users/28525/emersonjr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2016-11-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved the issue.
I thought about describing right here what i've done to solve it, but as this is an issue more related to AUR package then ROS itself, the steps i've made to  get past of it are documented here:

https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/ros-indigo-qt-gui-cpp/#news

---

Originally posted by [emersonjr](https://answers.ros.org/users/28525/emersonjr/) with karma: 16 on 2016-11-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0